# Transforming dataframe in python 3.7 with panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame using python 3.7.

The data frame I am using is from the pandas library

```
            bitcoin                  
               High      Low    Close
Date                                 
2018-05-14  8881.12  8367.97  8716.79
2018-05-15  8836.19  8456.45  8510.38
```

How can i transform it into the following condition?

```
Date           High      Low    Close                  
2018-05-14  8881.12  8367.97  8716.79
2018-05-15  8836.19  8456.45  8510.38
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This multiple index for dataframe

```
df.columns=df.columns.get_level_values(1)

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: df.bitcoin.reset_index()